# What is the expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I encounter the following formula in some textbook. However, I can not understand what the expansion in this formula is. Is there anyone giving some tips?

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= -\frac{iU}{2 \epsilon} \pm \sqrt{\frac{i\omega}{\epsilon} - \frac{U^{2}}{4 \epsilon^{2}}} \\
&= \frac{iU}{2 \epsilon} \pm \frac{iU}{2 \epsilon} \left [ 1 - \frac{2i\omega \epsilon}{U^{2}} + \frac{2 \omega^{2} \epsilon^{2}}{U^{4}} + O(\epsilon^{3}) \right ]
\end{align}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: What are the various variables ?  You should include a little background

Comment: Exactly what parts of it do you not understand?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I mean the expansion is for \epsilon. And I did not understand how the expansion works.

Comment: That textbook should have said somewhere "$\epsilon \to 0$".  If it didn't, complain to the author!

Comment: Haha, it actually said. I did not add the details here, since I think it's not the key point and most guys know it when dealing with expansions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

They factored out $\;-\dfrac{U^2}{4\varepsilon^2}=\biggl(\dfrac{iU}{2\varepsilon}\biggr)^2$ under the radical:
$$\sqrt{\frac{i\omega}{\epsilon} - \frac{U^{2}}{4 \epsilon^{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{-U^2}{4\varepsilon^2}\biggl(1-\frac{4i\omega\varepsilon}{U^2}\biggr)}=\dfrac{iU}{2\varepsilon}\sqrt{1-\frac{4i\omega\varepsilon\mathstrut}{U^2}},$$
and applied the development of $\sqrt{1-x}$ at order $2$:
$$\sqrt{1-x}=1-\frac12 x-\frac18x^2+O(x^3).$$